# IPFS- How to send message from a peer to another?

Tags: node.js, ipfs, libp2p

I am looking for a solution to send a message from an IPFS peer to another

in the [github doc](https://github.com/ipfs/js-ipfs) I found this code that connect a peer to another one :

```
ipfs.swarm.connect(addr, function (err) {
  if (err) {
    throw err
  }
  // if no err is present, connection is now open
})
```

but after connection there is nothing to do according to documentation.

There a solution named [ipfs-pubsub-room](https://github.com/ipfs-shipyard/ipfs-pubsub-room) that deal with messaging between peers, but there is no CDN for browser.

Answer (score 5):

`ipfs.swarm.connect` will simply *connect* both nodes so that they can exchange files.

ipfs-pubsub-room should work just fine from a browser but yes, you'll need to package it yourself.

However, you can *also* use [libp2p](https://libp2p.io), IPFS's networking library, directly via the `ipfs.libp2p` property if you just need to send a message directly from one peer to another.

To *listen* for inbound messages, you can register a "protocol handler" on one of your nodes:

```js
const pull = require('pull-stream')
ipfs.libp2p.handle('/my/protocol/name/1.0.0', (protocolName, connection) => {
  pull(connection, pull.collect((err, data) => {
    console.log("received:", data.toString())
  }))
})
```

(Where `ipfs` is an [initialized](https://github.com/ipfs/js-ipfs/#ipfs-module) IPFS node object, not the `IPFS` import.)

To send a message, you'll have to "dial" the peer/protocol:

```js
const pull = require('pull-stream')
ipfs.libp2p.dialProtocol(addr, '/my/protocol/name/1.0.0', (err, connection) => {
  pull(pull.values(["my message"]), connection)
})
```

You can find a complete example in the [js-ipfs documentation](https://github.com/libp2p/js-libp2p/tree/master/examples/echo).

Comment: Does "dial" open a new connection if you already have one via `node.swarm.connect(addr)`? The name seems to suggest so.

Comment: Apparently the answer is no, it will reuse the existing connection and just open a new stream. [source](https://discuss.libp2p.io/t/send-message-to-already-connected-peer-context-ipfs/240/2)

Comment: Will it be private or public?

Answer (score -2):

IPFS is a file system, so once you have two peers connected they can `add` and `get` files to share content between those nodes. If your "message" can be encoded as a file that node A adds (https://docs.ipfs.io/reference/api/cli/#ipfs-add) and node B gets (https://docs.ipfs.io/reference/api/cli/#ipfs-get), then they can exchange messages that way.

Check out https://docs.ipfs.io/introduction/usage/ for general usage instructions.